# How to make a common collider for 2 objects in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I made two dices and I want to play both animations of them when I click in one of two dices. I tried to widespread polygon collider to cover both dices but i failed. Anyone can give me an advise? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some of the related code you have, and elaborate on the result you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I think this is none of the code's issue, because  i'm working on unity so there maybe a way to resolve the problem on unity, i guess?

Comment: I just want to click one times and both dices play animation ^^

Comment: Ok I understand the result you want to get, but you have not shown me how you are trying to achieve it. What code have you used and what have you done in Unity to try to achieve the result?

Comment: I added polygon collider in each dice, then I make it wide enough to cover both of them. In C# script, I wrote anim.enabled = true when MouseDown

Comment: Did you make sure to specify that the animation is being triggered on both dice's animation controllers? Are you sure that you are reading the mouse input correctly, and on the correct collider? And did you add the script to the correct game object in the inspector? Also keep in mind, the more details and code you provide, the better I can help.

Comment: Possibly not related to the tag unity-container?